# How to Flatten mixed multilevel list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to `Flatten`

```
t1={{5, 12, 13}, {21, 20, 29}, {15, 8, 
  17}, {{-7, -12, -11}, {19, 20, 31}, {13, 8, 19}}, {{77, 68, 
   105}, {61, 60, 89}, {97, 88, 135}}, {{67, 44, 79}, {41, 12, 
   37}, {77, 40, 
   83}}, {{{-27, -60, -63}, {-21, -76, -73}, {-27, -88, -85}}, {{43, \
-4, 31}, {59, 4, 47}, {83, 8, 69}}, {{33, -28, 
    5}, {39, -44, -5}, {63, -40, 17}}}, {{{281, 212, 357}, {223, 164, 
    283}, {361, 264, 455}}, {{197, 132, 241}, {181, 124, 225}, {277, 
    184, 339}}, {{341, 244, 425}, {283, 196, 351}, {451, 312, 
    557}}}, {{{295, 236, 379}, {185, 124, 221}, {335, 248, 
    417}}, {{225, 180, 285}, {105, 44, 101}, {225, 152, 263}}, {{369, 
    292, 469}, {207, 116, 227}, {399, 280, 481}}}}
```

to

```
{{5, 12, 13}, {21, 20, 29}, {15, 8, 17}, {-7, -12, -11}, {19, 20, 
  31}, {13, 8, 19}, {77, 68, 105}, {61, 60, 89}, {97, 88, 135}, {67, 
  44, 79}, {41, 12, 37}, {77, 40, 
  83}, {-27, -60, -63}, {-21, -76, -73}, {-27, -88, -85}, {43, -4, 
  31}, {59, 4, 47}, {83, 8, 69}, {33, -28, 
  5}, {39, -44, -5}, {63, -40, 17}, {281, 212, 357}, {223, 164, 
  283}, {361, 264, 455}, {197, 132, 241}, {181, 124, 225}, {277, 184, 
  339}, {341, 244, 425}, {283, 196, 351}, {451, 312, 557}, {295, 236, 
  379}, {185, 124, 221}, {335, 248, 417}, {225, 180, 285}, {105, 44, 
  101}, {225, 152, 263}, {369, 292, 469}, {207, 116, 227}, {399, 280, 
  481}}
```

by using `Flatten`. I could do it by

```
Partition[Flatten[t1], 3, 3]
```

but want to learn how to use `Flatten` properly.

Comment: It is not clear to me why you use `Partition[Flatten[t1], 3,3]` and not `Partition[Flatten[t1], 3]`

Comment: You are tight. I took one step too many.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest and cleanest alternative to `Flatten` is suggested by @Syed and is using the command [`Level`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html).

Having said that, another approach is to use [`FlattenAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FlattenAt.html)

```
 = FlattenAt[#, Position[Depth /@ # - 2, 1]] &;
[ /@ t1]
```

> {{5, 12, 13}, {21, 20, 29}, {15, 8, 17}, {-7, -12, -11}, {19, 20,
> 31}, {13, 8, 19}, {77, 68, 105}, {61, 60, 89}, {97, 88, 135}, {67,
> 44, 79}, {41, 12, 37}, {77, 40,
> 83}, {-27, -60, -63}, {-21, -76, -73}, {-27, -88, -85}, {43, -4,
> 31}, {59, 4, 47}, {83, 8, 69}, {33, -28,
> 5}, {39, -44, -5}, {63, -40, 17}, {281, 212, 357}, {223, 164,
> 283}, {361, 264, 455}, {197, 132, 241}, {181, 124, 225}, {277, 184,
> 339}, {341, 244, 425}, {283, 196, 351}, {451, 312, 557}, {295, 236,
> 379}, {185, 124, 221}, {335, 248, 417}, {225, 180, 285}, {105, 44,
> 101}, {225, 152, 263}, {369, 292, 469}, {207, 116, 227}, {399, 280,
> 481}}

Comment: Why did you delete `Level[t1,{-2}]` ? It was informative!

Comment: @user57467 as I said it was suggested first in the answer by Syed. I had not seen it and observed it later. Deleting it seems the proper thing to do

Answer (score 4):

```
t1 = {{5, 12, 13}, {21, 20, 29}, {15, 8, 
      17}, {{-7, -12, -11}, {19, 20, 31}, {13, 8, 19}}, {{77, 68, 
        105}, {61, 60, 89}, {97, 88, 135}}, {{67, 44, 79}, {41, 12, 
        37}, {77, 40, 
        83}}, {{{-27, -60, -63}, {-21, -76, -73}, {-27, -88, -85}}, \
{{43, \
       -4, 31}, {59, 4, 47}, {83, 8, 69}}, {{33, -28, 
          5}, {39, -44, -5}, {63, -40, 17}}}, {{{281, 212, 
      357}, {223, 164, 
          283}, {361, 264, 455}}, {{197, 132, 241}, {181, 124, 
      225}, {277, 
          184, 339}}, {{341, 244, 425}, {283, 196, 351}, {451, 312, 
          557}}}, {{{295, 236, 379}, {185, 124, 221}, {335, 248, 
          417}}, {{225, 180, 285}, {105, 44, 101}, {225, 152, 
      263}}, {{369, 
          292, 469}, {207, 116, 227}, {399, 280, 481}}}};

Level[t1, {-2}]
```

---

Can I do it with `Flatten`? Can't say that I know how to. Here is another workaround.

```
Extract[#, Position[_?VectorQ][#]] &@t1
```

---

*Result:*

> {{5, 12, 13}, {21, 20, 29}, {15, 8, 17}, {-7, -12, -11}, {19, 20,
> 31}, {13, 8, 19}, {77, 68, 105}, {61, 60, 89}, {97, 88, 135}, {67,
> 44, 79}, {41, 12, 37}, {77, 40,    83}, {-27, -60, -63}, {-21, -76,
> -73}, {-27, -88, -85}, {43, -4,    31}, {59, 4, 47}, {83, 8, 69}, {33, -28,    5}, {39, -44, -5}, {63, -40, 17}, {281, 212, 357}, {223, 164,    283}, {361, 264, 455}, {197, 132, 241}, {181, 124, 225}, {277, 184,
> 339}, {341, 244, 425}, {283, 196, 351}, {451, 312, 557}, {295, 236,
> 379}, {185, 124, 221}, {335, 248, 417}, {225, 180, 285}, {105, 44,
> 101}, {225, 152, 263}, {369, 292, 469}, {207, 116, 227}, {399, 280,
> 481}}

Comment: Very good! And how would you use `Flatten` in this case?

Comment: Can't say that I know how to use `Flatten` with multi level lists. But I have added a workaround. @user57467

Comment: `Cases[t1, {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ}, Infinity]` as a non-Flatten alternative

Comment: @Syed I am sorry. I just realised that you had used the `Level` command to solve this. The way it was written my eye caught the `Extract` solution. Let me know, when you see this one and I will update my answer. Sorry again

Comment: I am in awe of the `FlattenAt` solution you've posted. @bmf

Comment: @Syed thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 3):

We can build a piecewise function that does the job:

```
f[l_List] := Piecewise[{{l, VectorQ[l] === True}, {Splice@Catenate@l, 
             MatrixQ[l] === False}, {Splice@l, MatrixQ[l] === True}}]
```

Comparing with @Syed's answer:

```
f /@ t1 === Extract[#, Position[_?VectorQ][#]] &@t1

(*True*)
```